# How to write piecewise function in netlogo for agent simulation?

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing Multi agent simulation using Netlogo, but in Netlogo, there is no suitable math expression for defining a piecewise function. 
Anyone knows how to solve this ?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
to-report unitstep [#x]
  report ifelse-value (#x < 0) [0] [1]
end
```

**Edit:**
If you want steps at multiple points, you could do this:

```
to-report n-steps [#x]
  let steps [1 2 3]
  let n 0
  foreach steps [
    set n (n + unitstep (#x - ?))
  ]
  report n
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. This expression would work for a piecewise function with 2 conditions, but for functions with more than two conditions , the ifelse-value report would not work, shall I replace the ifelse-value by if?@King-Ink

Comment: nested `ifelse-value` like `ifelse-value (xx < 5) [1] [ifelse-value xx < 10 [2] [3] ]`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to write it functionally as a to-report

this snippet may help

```
to-report thing [X]
   ifelse x < 10 and x > 5 [report 3][report x ^ 2]
   end
```